# How to reduce Line In playback delay?

Tags: windows-10, audio

I connected my Roland D-10 synthesizer to my PC (Windows 10 version 20H2) using Line In, and I turned on playback. However, there is an annoying delay in playback (200-500 ms). I would like to reduce the playback delay/latency to minimum.

Since I am using Hungarian Windows, it is better if I show you pictures:

Here is how I enabled playback:

[image: Image of how I enabled playback]

By using google, there was a recommendation to enable playback through playback devices level settings, but there is no option for me:

[image: Playback options]

So far I did not have any external audio driver installed, the auto installed win 10 version was fine, but I also installed [the latest audio driver for my motherboard](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/b150m-mortar#down-driver&Win10%2064) but after installing I couldn't find any playback setting on the GUI for that, so I uninstalled the driver as it didn't help.

Currently I am using a FiiO E10K Olympus 2 DAC AMP for playback, but I also tried to set playback to a headphone directly connected to one the motherboard's jack connectors, but the latency was still there, so it is not caused by my DAC.

For context, years ago when I was still using Windows 7 with a different hardware I had this set up perfectly (no noticable delay) and it worked perfectly, so I cannot believe it can't work like that with way more modern equipment and software.

I also tried to listen to the synthesizer directly with a headphone and there was no delay, so it is 100% the PC is causing this.

Can you please help me solving this issue?

---

Edit:
**Solution**

The solution for me was to install the motherboard's audio driver, and set up playback there. I also had to connect my speakers through jack so the audio driver can detect it and use that for playback. That way, the audio latency was gone (or so low I could not feel it, doesn't matter).
See the image:
[image: Realtek HD audio control panel, line in tab]

**Also, there may be another - but more complex - way to make this work by setting up a Virtual Audio Cable with VoiceMeeter but it was too much for me.**

Comment: I don't see a D-10 mentioned among the [Roland drivers](https://www.roland.com/global/support/updates_drivers/). Are you sure about the model name?

Comment: @harrymc Yes.Try google searching "roland d-10 manual".

Comment: You probably do not see it among roland driver list since it is an old model (1988).

Comment: There is no point then in searching for a driver, it won't be compatible with Windows 10. I can't help as regarding software.

Comment: Thank you for trying, though. When I used it on Win7 I didn't have to install any drivers, so I'm quite sure there should be a way (setting, or something) to achieve the same state without a driver. I mean, why would anyone need a driver for simply redirecting audio? It is quite simple: signal comes in on the LINE IN port, and redirect it to the given output without any change. That's all, no logic needed.

Comment: If you still have Windows 7, check which driver is used.

Comment: I don't know why are we still talking about drivers, I did not need a driver, and I believe I do not need one now either. (By the way that system is long gone, both hardware and software)

Comment: All hardware has a driver, regardless of if you ever see it When you say you "did not need a driver" you mean that Windows came with the driver. Windows 10 doesn't come with the same drivers as Win7 so it is relevant.

Comment: There is no reason to look for Roland drivers if you are using line in. You need an ASIO driver such as ASIO4ALL or FlexASIO if your soundcard mfg does not provide one. This is basically a duplicate of a number of posts on https://music.stackexchange.com search for ASIO on that stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Yorik stated [a similar question was asked & got a similar answer: onboard sound cards have delays](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/24824/windows-7-line-in-latency-issue). One of the answers on that page details your question of [why did it work on older HW & SW: built-in sound cards have simply changed](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/24824/windows-7-line-in-latency-issue/24827#24827).

If I were in your shoes I'd personally re-investigate those sound drivers. Per that question & skimming some stuff online Windows seems to prefer it's built-in WDM drivers that make the delay worse compared to the Realtek drivers. I don't know what you mean by:

> I couldn't find any playback setting on the GUI for that

The audio driver usually replaces a lot of the functionality of the Window Settings/Control-Panel sound option in its own 'app'. Sometimes that doesn't show up in the Windows/Start menu so you may have to go to Control Panel & look for it there. I don't think this will entirely fix the latency/delay, but hopefully it will help you.

As for why we keep talking about drivers: they simply control how the sound is processed. As noted above in that duplicate question link its unlikely an actual wire connects the Line In jack to the Speaker jack, its doing a lot of processing which causes the delay. The computer has to be able to 'capture' the sound & the jacks are modular & can be re-assigned. That's just an example of a little bit of under-the-hood processing drivers handle they are likely to contribute to the latency/delay.

Answer (score 0):

Your onboard soundcard is not a good way to capture sound input.

To solve the problem you need to buy a low latency audio interface. There are plenty of devices made to solve this problem. It can get quite expensive because this is the kind of hardware used to record music.

If you are not able\willing to buy the proper hardware there are software solutions that may give you a better experience than the built-in Windows tools.

The best example I have is [VoiceMeeter Banana](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm):

This software gives you the kind of hardware controls you would see on dedicated audio hardware.

More specifically for you there is a tool they provide called [Virtual Audio Cable](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm). This allows you to virtually connect any two audio devices on your computer like the input and output you show in your pictures.

Comment: The real question is: why did it work flawlessly with older hw+sw, and not with a more modern one? I literally used the cheapest motherboards back then. I understand that buying expensive studio-grade audio equipment is one solution, but I can't believe it is the only one.

Comment: @KárolyOzsvárt I added an example of some software that will do what you want. It's no match for good hardware and, in fact, could be used in conjunction with good hardware. A proper audio capture devices doesn't have to be too expensive. Even a Schiit Hella or Fulla would give you an external device that would eliminate the noise in a PC onboard audio device.

Comment: Try the virtual audio cable I linked. I think that may be the immediate answer you are looking for. It's free.